# how to unify legends in plot3d?

Tags: r, plot

I saw the following code in an example of plot3d:

```
      par(mfrow = c(2, 2))

      # keep ratios between x- and y (scale = FALSE) 
      # change ratio between x- and z (expand)
      persp3D(z = volcano, x = 1: nrow(volcano), y = 1:ncol(volcano),
          expand = 0.3, main = "volcano", facets = FALSE, scale = FALSE,
          clab = "height, m", colkey = list(side = 1, length = 0.5))

      # ribbon, in x--direction
      V <- volcano[, seq(1, ncol(volcano), by = 3)]  # lower resolution

      ribbon3D(z = V, colkey = list(width = 0.5, length = 0.5, 
            cex.axis = 0.8, side = 2), clab = "m")

      # ribbon, in y-direction
      Vy <- volcano[seq(1, nrow(volcano), by = 3), ]

      ribbon3D(z = Vy, expand = 0.3, space = 0.3, along = "y", 
         colkey = list(width = 0.5, length = 0.5, cex.axis = 0.8))
```

This prints four plots, but they each have their own legend.

I want to create similar 3d histograms, only my "Z" have all the same range, and I want to use just a single legend.

So what I want to do is:

1. Be able to draw just the legend (so I can save it to a file) for all unified histograms, where it is printed horizontally.
2. Make all legends in all small plots disappear.

I would also appreciate just an answer to one of these questions.

Comment: I guessing this is from the 'plot3D' package, but it's only a guess. Please do not make us guess which package is being used.